# How to program a spell checker, similar to Yahoo! Answers?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Are there toturails available or any javascript libraries? Thanks.

Comment: Oh the irony. It burns.

Comment: i think i had toturails for dinner

Comment: totu on rails is the latest programming hotness.

Comment: Why would you want to do this with modern day browsers that have a spell checker built in? Seems like you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: please forgive my friends, they're just having fun, don't take offense or let them scare you away ;D

Answer (score 3):

[A Spellchecker Used to Be a Major Feat of Software Engineering](http://prog21.dadgum.com/29.html).

Answer (score 1):

check out this [link on the theory](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) of spell checking... with links at the bottom to the language of your choice. It's Peter Norvig's "How to Write a Spelling Corrector" page.

Answer (score 1):

You could plug into googles spellchecker with this script:
http://orangoo.com/labs/GoogieSpell/